# Is it possible to use vim key bindings in iterm2?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, vim, iterm2

I want to use `w` for next word and `b` for previous word. If I could do more than that I would be even happier.

I use bash if that matters.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm surprised you haven't yet found out about

```
set -o vi
```

This enables the *vi editing mode* in Bash (to make this permanent put the command in your `~/.bashrc` file). [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/set-o-vi-emacs) has a short summary, and [here's a Unix & Linux question about its advantages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30454/advantages-of-using-set-o-vi).

This setting is for the Bash shell, regardless of the terminal (who's purpose is to provide a container for typing and seeing text (plus selecting and pasting with the mouse) - apart from tabbed windows and some global window management, it shouldn't interfere with what's running inside it).

To enable this for some more (terminal-based) applications that use the *readline library* for input, you can put this into `~/.inputrc`

```
# Do what "set -o vi" does in Bash to whatever uses readline.
set editing-mode vi
```

Comment: It's 2023, I've been using the terminal for 15 years now and I find this out....only now?

Comment: @pyronaur Better late than never ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised it is mentioned here, so I'll mention it for completeness' sake. Also for the **zsh** shell, the way of setting vi keybinding is different from **bash**.

In zsh vi keybinding are set with:

```
bindkey -v
```

For a gentle introduction, you can read [here](https://sgeb.io/posts/zsh-zle-custom-widgets/).
After which, the [official documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide04.html#l75) should look less intimidating.

Answer (score 2):

For **zsh** users that use **vim**(not **vi**):

In addition to adding the **vi** keybinding, you should avoid the **vi**-related backspace issue(backspace stops working) by putting the following two statements in your `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
# use vi key bindings
bindkey -v
# avoid the annoying backspace/delete issue 
# where backspace stops deleting characters
bindkey -v '^?' backward-delete-char
```

The backspace issue has been discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290392/backspace-in-zsh-stuck/290403#290403) in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

For **Fish** shell users, put the command `fish_vi_key_bindings` into your config. Default location is: `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

For more details, see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28445450

Answer (score 0):

#### Best option I found

After googling for many hours, and came across this amazing zhs-shell plugin called
https://github.com/jeffreytse/zsh-vi-mode

It got so many cool features like delete between brackets, quotations ..etc. These features not available in the original `vim-mode` plugin that comes with `oh-my-zsh` (without tweaking and configuring of course).
simply add it to your zsh-shell script plugin manger in your `.zshrc` that's all.
I hope this would be useful for anyone wish to have vim-command in his iTerm, or any other terminal application.
tested for both `Alacrity` and `iTerm2` btw.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).